# return parameter in lua

Tags: lua, return, parameter-passing

```
format = function(&Return, Length, Format, ...)
    Return = string.format(Format, ...);
    Return = string.sub(Format, 0, Length);
    return 1;
end

local Test;

format(Test, 12, "Hello world %s! This is a test.", "Hello World");

print(Test);
```

I would love this to print, "Hello world!" without it being returned by the function but being returned by the parameter.

Comment: You do know that Lua functions return lists (i.e., 0 or more values), right?

Comment: Yes I am aware you can return multi-variables, thank you for responding, moteus has the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like

```
local function Pointer()
  return setmetatable({},{
    __tostring = function(self) return self.value end
  })
end

format = function(Return, Length, Format, ...)
  Return.value = string.sub(Format, 0, Length)
  return 1
end

local Test = Pointer()

format(Test, 12, "Hello world %s! This is a test.", "Hello World")

print(Test)
```

Comment: Nice trick! But one should mention that this nice syntax only works because `print` automatically calls the `__tostring` metamethod. In most other cases you would need to write `Test.value` to access the result.

Comment: May be we can use proxy with metamethod __len ( value = #Test )

Comment: moteus, you deserve a gold medal my friend but all I can unfortunately give you is my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are not accessing `Return`, just setting it; also you are not using the returned value '1'. So: why not do this:

```
format = function(Length, Format, ...)
    local Return = string.format(Format, ...)
    Return = string.sub(Format, 0, Length)
    local status = 1 -- i'm guessing this is a status code of sorts
    return Return, status
end

local Test, stat = format(12, "Hello world %s! This is a test.", "Hello World")
```

Code review notes:

- based on the fact that you are using semicolons everywhere and &Return as a function parameter, seems to me you are still "thinking in C". Don't. When you program in Lua, think in Lua. In Lua, you can return multiple values, and there is no need for semicolons, so why clutter the code with unnecessary symbols.
- I recommend keeping all format components together, plus this way you can easily extend it:

  ```
  local Test, stat = format("Hello world %s! This is a test.", 
                           ["Hello World", 12], ['Joe', 5])
  ```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but moteus has the best solution to my problem. - I use semicolons because it's optional and most programming languages use semicolon to end statements; so I naturally just do it (I have problems using != instead of ~= and || && instead of 'or' 'and' so...)